# How to calculate clock ticks of only the current process (including all thread)

Tags: c, time, process, clock

All is in the title.

In time.h :

> The C library function clock_t clock(void)returns the number of clock
>   ticks elapsed since the program was launched

But for the current process or all process of the OS ?

Thx.

Comment: So how to know the real time elapsed on a program. The time consuming depends on others program, not realy on the current program...

Comment: Sorry, wrong function. `clock` returns the current process' approximate processor time in clock ticks. So it applies only to process calling `clock`.

Comment: Meaning what? I don't understand the question.

Comment: There are operating system specific functions that can give you this kind of info.  Whenever you ask OS specific questions then you should of course mention what you use.  And assume that you are not the first SO user that asked such a question.

Comment: Note that POSIX systems now have an updated set of clock functions: `clock_gettime`, `clock_getres`, etc...

Comment: Sry I mean do you have references?, but it's ok : http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock.html @isedev. So this is actually the approximated clock ticks, good.

Comment: Approximate because the scheduler can't take into account partial clock ticks when summing the elapsed time of the process. However, statistically the errors should average out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx isedev.
This is actually the approximated clock ticks of the current process.

```
clock_t t;
t = clock();
printf ("Calculating...\n");
float u = 0;
for(int i = 0 ; i < 1000000 ; i++)
    u += sqrt(i);
printf("%f", u);
t = clock() - t;
printf ("%d clock ticks elapsed\n%f ms elapsed.\n", t, ((float) t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
```